# How to calculate sal of employe whose name starts with a,b,c.....?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
create table Emp(emp_name varchar(20),emp_sal int)

insert into Emp values
('amit',100),('animesh',200),('ashish',300),('ashok',400),
('ramesh',500),('ratan',600),('rajesh',700),
('lokesh',300),('lalit',900),('lakhan',800)
```

> Can i calculate sum of the salary of employees whose name starts with 'A', 'R', 'L' and Even I want it show in table with a unique id like

```
emp_id         total_sal
 A               1000
 R               1800
 L               2000
```

> I have tried like this

```
select sum(emp_sal)as from emp where emp_name like 'a%'
```

> but dont know what to do next

Comment: Why is this question tagged both [tag:mysql] (which relates to a free, open-source, cross-platform RDBMS product now owned by The Oracle Corporation) and [tag:sql-server] (which relates to a commercial, closed-source, proprietary, Windows-only RDBMS product from Microsoft)?

Comment: Sir I'm beginner Please help me out

Comment: Perhaps if you clarified *which* RDBMS product you are actually using, it might be a little easier to give you a correct answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(emp_name, 1) first_letter, sum(emp_sal)
  FROM emp
  WHERE LEFT(emp_name, 1) IN ('a', 'r', 'l')
  GROUP BY LEFT(emp_name, 1);
```

example fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/436b8/2

And works in both mysql and sql-server.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking interest here. Its working

Answer (score 0):

this works almost all RDBMSs, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, Postgre,... as you tagged more than one RDBMS in the question

```
select q.emp_id, sum(q.emp_sal)
from (
select case 
           when emp_name like 'A%' then 'A'
           when emp_name like 'R%' then 'R'
           when emp_name like 'L%' then 'L'
        end as emp_id,
       emp_sal 
from emp where emp_name like 'A%' or emp_name like 'R%' or emp_name like 'L%'
) q
group by  q.emp_id
```

Comment: it may work in both, but would be optimal in neither

Comment: @pala_, don't have any doubt , don't say `it may`, say `for sure it will work for both`. also I think the art is to know about a common solution not separated solution for each because the OP may have one app on multiple db and because of many other reason

Comment: tbh i didnt see the sql-server tag when i answered, lucked out with one that worked in both anyway

Answer (score 0):

select upper(substring(emp_name,1,1)),sum(emp_sal) from emp
where emp_name like ('a%') or emp_name like ('r%') or emp_name like ('l%')
group by upper(substring(emp_name,1,1))